# Unable to create spaces between the buttons and to center the text to the center

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

i have in my page 4 buttons,

Unable to create spaces between the buttons and to center  the text to the center

this is my code:

```
<fieldset data-type="horizontal">
    <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:20%"><button><p style="font-size:10px;">A</p></button></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:20%"><button><p style="font-size:10px;">B</p></button></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:20%"><button><p style="font-size:10px;">C</p></button></div>
    <div class="ui-block-d" style="width:20%"><button><p style="font-size:10px;">D</p></button></div>
</fieldset>
```

the result is:

```
[ AA][  BB][   CC].....
```

Regards,

thanks for all the help :)

i try all this things and i see the buttons still without spaces between.

i see:

```
[AAA][BBB][CCC][DDD]
```

and i want to see:

```
[AAA]  [BBB]  [CCC]  [DDD]
```

Comment: Try adding `margin-right` and `text-align: center` to the `ui-block-*` divs.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/grids-buttons/

Answer (score 0):

to center text use

```
text-align:center;
```

to have spaces between the buttons, change the left/right margins of each of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
p{
 width:100;
 text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default button takes the width to adjust the text inside.
In your case the text is very small A,B...

use css width property for button to get spaces in between

```
 div{
    display:inline-block;
}

button{
    width:90%; // adjust this to get spaces
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/LorLx11f/1/

this should work